# iOS like day view calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, calendar

For my website I need a day view calendar view that I want to look like the iOS calendar. On GitHub I found hcal.js, which does exactly this, but has a couple missing features that I needed. I've made some changes to the existing code and managed to get most of it working, except for placing the appointments next to each other when they collide with another.

Link to original hcal source: [GitHub hcal.js](https://github.com/valnub/hcal)
Link to my version on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/suwagimawu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

The function below I made to check for colliding appointments and to change the width of an appointment. It simply checks the times and determines if there's a collision. All appointments one appointment collides with are pushed into an array, this is then used to calculate the width of an appointment. So lets say an appointment collides with 2 other appointments then the width would be 100%/3=33,333%. Right now I'm trying to calculate the right margin for each appointment, so appointments that collide with each other are put next to each other instead of on top of each other.

One appointment item contains the following: an array with the start time in hours and minutes, an array with the end time in hours and minutes, a title string, a location string, a description string, the color id, a table which contains the items the current item collides with (ordered by start time, including itself) and a unique identifier.

```
function formatHcalAppointments() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $.fn.items.length; i++) {
        $.fn.items[i][6] = [];

        for (var k = 0; k < $.fn.items.length; k++) {
            var iTimeStart = $.fn.items[i][0][0] + ($.fn.items[i][0][1]/100),
                iTimeEnd = $.fn.items[i][1][0] + ($.fn.items[i][1][1]/100),
                kTimeStart = $.fn.items[k][0][0] + ($.fn.items[k][0][1]/100),
                kTimeEnd = $.fn.items[k][1][0] + ($.fn.items[k][1][1]/100);

            if (((iTimeStart >= kTimeStart) && (iTimeStart <= kTimeEnd)) || ((iTimeEnd >= kTimeStart) && (iTimeStart <= kTimeEnd))) {
                $.fn.items[i][6].push(k);
            }
        }
    }
  
    for (var i = 0; i < $.fn.items.length; i++) {
        var $item = $('.hcal-item-' + $.fn.items[i][7]);

        var width = 100 - ((75 / window.innerWidth) * 100);

        var count = $.fn.items[i][6].length;
        var length = (count == 0) ? 1 : count;

        for (var k in $.fn.items[i][6]) {
            var n = $.fn.items[i][6][k];

            if ($.fn.items[n][6].length > count) {
                length = $.fn.items[n][6].length;
            }
        }

        $item.css({
            'width': (width/length) + '%',
            'margin-right': '0%'
        });
    }
}
```

I know this is not much information, but I don't really know how to be more specific. I would like a push in the right direction, I've been messing around with this way too long now without any result.

Cheers.

Comment: please post the relevant code segment you're referring to.

Comment: I have updated the post, I hope it's a bit more understandable what I exactly mean now.